# How can I import to Excel a .txt with columns as rows (no delimiters)?

Tags: excel

The problem I face is the following:

I have a .txt with data as:

---

```
Name: Neo
Age: 30
Class: Human
(Blank row)
Name: Morpheus
Age: 150
Class: Human
(Blank row)
[...] (and so on)
```

---

And I would like to import it to Excel, in order to have every row "Name" as the first column, every row "Age" as the second column, and the same with Class in the third one. Also I need to "skip" those Blank rows.

How can I do that? The Import .txt wizard doesn't help, as it provides only delimiters as commas, tabs, and other chars.

Also, I would like to have it as a .csv file. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: This can be accomplished using VBA. Are you open to using it?

Comment: What is VBA? Just to know for the future...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Import your text file into Excel via menu Data / From Text. Choose `:` as delimiter. You should have your data in a new worksheet in columns `A:B`.
2. Write this formula into column `C:C` and drag it down:

   =INDEX($B:$B,ROW()*4-3)

Column `D:D`:

```
=INDEX($B:$B,ROW()*4-2)
```

Column `E:E`:

```
=INDEX($B:$B,ROW()*4-1).
```

You should have it like in the picture:

[image]